# React API call status is pending forever

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, routes, axios

[I am making API calls from my CRA (Create React App). Sometimes while opening a random page all of the API calls are showing the status of "pending" forever. When I refresh my page then, all the APIs work fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6r4D.png)

[These are the details of the API in "pending" status.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVRXE.png)

```
const checkWelcomeRewardShown = async () => {
    try {
        if (localStorage.getItem("userType") === "student") {
            let res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/gethasnotseenintro`);
            if (res?.data?.status === "success" && res?.data?.notSeen) {
                await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/getunlocktokenuser`);

                await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/falsewhenfirstlogin`);
            }

            let response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/seenPopupForLinkedinAndFeedback`);
        }
    } catch (error) {}
};

useEffect(() => {
    checkWelcomeRewardShown();
    dispatch(showAllPopups());
}, [localStorage.getItem("user_id")]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved. There was an API in Backend that was failing and there was no logic for what should happen if it fails. This was like a global level API that was being used everywhere so when it failed, it kind of blocked the execution of the rest of the APIs. That's why all of them were showing "pending".